# Can't kill exe task including cmd handler

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, process, ngrok

Whenever i try to kill the ngrok.exe task (`start /B "ngrok" call ngrok.exe tcp 22 -log=stdout > ngrok.log`) with taskkill (`taskkill /IM ngrok.exe /F`) it doesn't work. Apparently i kill the ngrok.exe process but Windows Command Prompt (session handler) is still there.

When I try to run the exe again it says: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

---

I've also tried to add `/T` to taskkill and get rid of any child processes, but it doesn't work too. Any solutions?

---

[Before any actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaHfp.png)

[After launching ngrok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZF4T.png)

[After taskkill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ixg.png)

Comment: I know this isn't your question but I myself don't understand your use of `call`.. this is for running batch processes from within other batch processes (either by label or file).  Have you tried ditching the start /b to see if it works when not running within the same terminal?

Comment: Also, for your edification.. how I myself would figure this out would be to use a better task manager (like sysinternals process explorer) and SEE what is going on.. sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words. =

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks for help, I deleted call command and everything works fine now :)

Comment: AWESOME @dheb :)  Glad it works now!!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, since you effectively fixed the issue, why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see is your use of the `call` command within your `start` command.

`call` is only used within a batch process to invoke functionality from within other batch processes (either by label or file).

ex:
`call :MyLabel`   <- where MyLabel is a label defined in the same file.
or
`call "c:\mypath\dumb.bat"` <- after this batch runs, it will continue from here

**In this case, this is not what you wan't as these are the only uses for call.**

### A quick lesson about the call command

Also, even though this wasn't what you wanted.. since we are on the subject of when to use `call`.. Why not simply use `goto` or directly invoke a batch file?

The reason for the label method is that `call` can be used like a function by calling a batch label.  After the label is called, the code after the label (sort of like a function) can return to where the call statement was invoked by either using `goto :EOF` or `exit /b` creating a very "function like" behavior within batch.  ***In the before times***, this was like `GoSub` and `Return` used in basic.

If you don't use `call` when invoking a batch file from another batch file, the process will simply exit after invoking the second batch file (leaving one bewildered as to why the batch stopped).

OTHERWISE, DON'T USE IT! :)